# Is there an app which supports both PDF and epub ebook formats?

Tags: pdf, ebook-reader, epub

Are there any apps which support both PDF and EPUB files?

I've tried Alkido, Laputa, and StarBooks, they only seem to support either PDF OR epub, not both.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

[Txtr](http://www.appbrain.com/app/txtr-ebook-reader-store/com.txtr.android) purports to support both, but hasn't gotten very good reviews.

[Speak Text Easy](http://www.appbrain.com/app/speak-text-easy/com.andrego.SpeakTextEasy) and [MultiReader](http://www.appbrain.com/app/multireader/bse.multireader) are primarily for text-to-speech, but they both appear to support both file formats.

Answer (score 2):

[Aldiko](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aldiko.android) is a good free application for reading PDF and ePub documents.

Comment: OP mentions that they have already tried Aldiko.

Comment: Aldiko supports pdf and epub according to the app description- "Advanced library management system: import your own **EPUB** and **PDF** files into the app to read them on the go" 
Probably in 2010 it didnt

Comment: @AlEverett yes but OP is from 2010. Pdf support is from 2011.

Comment: Okay, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Both Aldiko and FBreader support PDF reading without conversion. As the app should update, you can check them again.

I found these later: Aldiko only supports non-DRM'd EPUB.
NOOK for Android by B&N and Kobo eBooks seem support both PDF and EPUB.

Get the information from: http://www.pdfmate.com/read-pdf-with-ebook-reader-app-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using [BlueFire Reader](http://www.bluefirereader.com/). It is free of charge and can display PDF and ePub files with Adobe DRM.

Answer (score 0):

[Moon+ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader) in the Pro version supports almost all formats available, including ePub and PDF. You can even highlight and annotate text; with PDF files, these highlights/annotations will be directly embedded into the file (so you then can simply transfer the PDF to another reader and have your notes included), while for the other formats they are stored separately. Support is pretty good, fixes and new features are constantly released (developer is quite active and responding).